# Quaere - Anyone using it yet? (LINQ to Objects for Java)

Tags: java, collections, linq-to-objects

I'm a .NET guy originally, working in Java recently, and finding I'm really missing LINQ to Objects, specifically for performing filtering against collections.

A few people here on Stack Overflow have answered the "LINQ for Java?" question with a single word :

> [Quaere](http://quaere.codehaus.org/)

However, on the site it clearly states "Pre-Beta", and there's been no commits to their code for over a year, so I'm guessing the project is pretty much dead.

Is anyone actually using this, and / or have any experience with it?

The second most common answer appears to be "use Google Collections".  Is this the most appropriate Java way?

Cheers

Marty

Comment: For linq to objects check github.com/nicholas22/jpropel-light, real example:new String[] { "james", "john", "john", "eddie" }.where(startsWith("j")).toList().distinct();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the items in a collection (and much more) in a more readable way by using the lambdaj library

http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/

Comment: Yep, been using lambaj for a while since posting the question (but forgot to update.)

Thanks for the link -- it really is a great project.

Comment: I personally don't understand the hype around LINQ at all, especially after seeing what LambdaJ does (and how!). Definately worth a +1.

Comment: @Esko, compare `sort(persons, on(Person.class).getAge())` with LINQ's `persons.OrderBy(x => x.Age)`.   Furthremore, LambdaJ is fairly inefficient as demonstrated by their performance comparison: http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/PerformanceAnalysis.  Finally, this commentary hasn't even started on the expression trees in LINQ which allow for dramatic SQL projections of your operations directly into a database.

Comment: @Kirk You're asking me to compare `sort persons based on person's age` versus `persons, order them by their age`. Which one of these sound more correct to you? Also LambdaJ is slower than native methods, there's no surprises there since LambdaJ is built on top of proxies and reflection. As for LINQ, as is it really doesn't impress me, it needs to be combined with stuff like type inference to even make it interesting. As for SQL projections and whatnot, well, I guess that's important if you're still using SQL based data storages which I'm not so I don't really see that benefit either.

Comment: @Kirk Also note that my previous comment is over a year old, I do nowadays "get" LINQ a bit better but that still doesn't mean that I'd think it's great, it comes with its trade-offs and benefits as all technologies do and in my case the trade-offs are way bigger than the benefits.

Comment: @Esko, I don't have a preference in terms of the word `sort` and the word `OrderBy`.  I do have a *strong* preference towards invoking methods *on* something (expression **dot** expression) rather than having to know magic quasi-global "utility" methods like `sort` and `on`.  As for it not "impressing" you, my guess is you simply don't use .Net. -- as nobody who uses .Net avoids LINQ.

Comment: @Kirk My point was more that I like to read my code as fluently as possibly *(ref. fluent interfaces)* instead of reading it using machine logic unless I really have to.

Comment: @Esko -- strange you would say so.  The LINQ syntax is the quintessential example of a fluent interface. (method chains)

Comment: @Kirk Fluent interfaces are more than just chained methods, it's also about how the code actually *reads*. But I digress, this isn't relevant to this topic anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Quaere is in a pioneer position with LINQ in Java, but is not typesafe, which is one of the main points of LINQ.

[Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com) is type-safe and supports filtering, sorting and projecting Collections.

It supports operations on JPA/Hibernate, JDO and SQL backends as well.

The syntax is similar to SQL with the difference that the basic order is from-where-list.

I am the maintainer of Querydsl, so this answer is biased.

Answer (score 1):

For simple Linq To Objects, the best I think can be done in Java is something like this:

```
Vector<Integer> numbers = new Vector<Integer>();

numbers.add(42);
numbers.add(3);
numbers.add(16);
numbers.add(92);
numbers.add(9);

Iterable<Integer> filtered = new Where<Integer>(numbers) {
    protected boolean predicate(Integer i) { return i > 10; }
};

Iterable<String> converted = new Select<Integer, String>(filtered) {
    protected String select(Integer i) { return i.toString(); }
};

for (final String str : converted)
    System.out.println(str);
```

Note that I haven't got `Where` and `Select` chaining together in one expression. I could insert the definition of `filtered` into the one place it's used, but that would probably make it (even) less readable. The problems are the lack of extension methods and lambdas. The closest we can get to lambdas is by these anonymous class declarations. They can refer to objects named in the enclosing scope, but only `final`s, so they cannot mutate anything (unlike lambdas in C#).

Also the hugely verbose syntax is a pain. People have often proposed that Java should offer a simpler syntax for cases where there is only one abstract (or interface) method, and hence there is no need to give the name or type declarations for what you want to override. Then there's the fact that there's no type inference, and no obvious way to provide it on generic class constructors because `new Select(filtered)` already means something else.

The implementations for `Select` and `Where` are:

```
abstract class Select<TSource, TResult> implements Iterable<TResult>
{
    private Iterable<TSource> _source;

    public Select(Iterable<TSource> source)
        { _source = source; }

    private class Iter implements Iterator<TResult>
    {
        private Iterator<TSource> _i;

        public Iter() { _i = _source.iterator(); }

        public void remove()
            { _i.remove(); }

        public boolean hasNext()
            { return _i.hasNext(); }

        public TResult next()
            { return select(_i.next()); }
    }

    protected abstract TResult select(TSource source);

    public Iterator<TResult> iterator()
        { return new Iter(); }
}

abstract class Where<TSource> implements Iterable<TSource>
{
    private Iterable<TSource> _source;

    public Where(Iterable<TSource> source)
        { _source = source; }

    private class Iter implements Iterator<TSource>
    {
        private Iterator<TSource> _i;
        private TSource _cachedNext;
        private boolean _hasCachedNext;

        public Iter()
        {
            _i = _source.iterator();
            fetch();
        }

        public void remove()
            { _i.remove(); }

        public boolean hasNext()
            { return _hasCachedNext; }

        public TSource next()
        {
            TSource result = _cachedNext;
            fetch();
            return result;
        }

        private void fetch()
        {
            _hasCachedNext = false;

            while (_i.hasNext())
            {
                _cachedNext = _i.next();
                if (predicate(_cachedNext))
                {
                    _hasCachedNext = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract boolean predicate(TSource source);

    public Iterator<TSource> iterator()
        { return new Iter(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[SBQL4J](http://code.google.com/p/sbql4j/) may satisfy Your requirements. It's type safe extension to Java language, but it's also 100% compatible with Java 6 VM. SBQL4J provides capabilities similar to LINQ-to-objects.

Daniel's query examples should be like this:

```
Vector<Integer> numbers = new Vector<Integer>();

numbers.add(42);
numbers.add(3);
numbers.add(16);
numbers.add(92);
numbers.add(9);

Iterable<Integer> filtered = #{ numbers as n where n > 10 };

Iterable<String> converted = #{ numbers.toString() };

for (final String str : converted)
    System.out.println(str);
```

There are about 35 operators of the query language, including selection, projection, ordering, arithmetic operators, aggregation, transitive closure, range, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [extra166y addendum to JSR166y](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/) with the [ParallelArray](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/extra166ydocs/extra166y/ParallelArray.html) construct. Basically a PLINQ for object arrays.